# How can I initialize a generic mutable array in Swift?

Tags: ios, generics, swift, nsmutablearray

I tried this:

```
var ss: [S] = NSMutableArray<S>(capacity: 0)
```

Compiler says: *Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSMutableArray*'

Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are Objective C types, and do not support generics. You can instantiate as swift's native array type:

```
var settings = [Setting]()
```

which also can be written as

```
var settings = Array<Setting>()
```

Thanks to type inference, you don't have to specify the type, but if you like this are the complete versions:

```
var settings: [Setting] = [Setting]()
var settings: Array<Setting> = Array<Setting>()
```

Note that `[Setting]` and `Array<Setting>` are interchangeable, meaning they define the same object type, so you can use whichever you like more.

Comment: do you know how can I add elements from an `NSOrderedSet` to `settings`?

Comment: If not wrong `NSOrderedSet` has an `array` property of `NSArray` type. In order to take advantage of swift generics, you have to loop though that array, cast each element to Setting and add to the `settings` array

Comment: I was able to add sequences also with `+=` array generic operator

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know it was possible. Thanks for sharing that :)

Comment: You can use NSArray with generics in Objective-C! 
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-objective-c-lightweight-generics/

Comment: This answer is incomplete because the type `Array` cannot replace NSMutableArray 
 as it is immutable